# What's wrong with favicon.ico, sprockets and rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, sprockets

I'm getting the following error on my rails app when I try to precompile the assets. With a trace it says the following:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile --trace

** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: Unmatched double quote: "asset_path \"favicon.ico\" %>',"
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/shellwords.rb:83:in `block in shellsplit'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/shellwords.rb:81:in `scan'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/shellwords.rb:81:in `shellsplit'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:142:in `block in extract_directives'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:140:in `each'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:140:in `each_with_index'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:140:in `extract_directives'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:117:in `process_source'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:82:in `_call'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:68:in `call'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:196:in `dfs'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:134:in `block in find'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:133:in `each'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:133:in `find'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:185:in `compile'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/Users/admin/projects/RoR/bubblin/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
```

Splitting the trace here because stackoverflow wants more words over "code."

```
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `block in execute'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `each'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `execute'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:173:in `invoke'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/rake:22:in `load'
/Users/admin/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Weird; leave it for a month and something breaks in the meantime.

Comment: Where does that favicon line appear in your code?

Comment: Very ordinary, in the head of the layout: `= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico'`. It's with haml-rails.

Comment: and nowhere else?

Comment: Nope. In the `config/initializers/assets.rb` I do whitelist it though: With `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(serviceworker.js…  …*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif *.svg *.ico )

Comment: In the trace, it is showing a asset path and that's too in erb syntax `asset_path \"favicon.ico\" %>',` so there must be another use of favicon somewhere, other than the one you mentioned.

Comment: Got it. It's on `serviceworkers.js.erb`, but weird that it is breaking now. Had been working normally earlier. But thank you for forcing me to dig for it a little more.